# Styling option of multiple select

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code generated utilizing javascript.

```js
data = ['example', 'example2', 'example3']

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      var string = data[i].toLowerCase();
      $('#roles_user').append(`<option value="${data[i].authority}">${string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1)}</option>`);
    }
```

```css
 #roles_user option:checked {
        background: #F0D77E;
      }
    
      #roles_user option:hover {
        color: red;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select" id="roles_user" multiple required class="slct selectg selectium">
</select>
```

And I would like to change background color of the selected option.
I can change color on hover, but not on checked. When I select an option, the color is the default one (blue).

Comment: you can't style `option` elements, try to create a custom `select`.

Comment: @ths how do you mean custom select? Can I somehow style the selected option? Or is there no way?

Comment: no you can't style an `option` as it's a `replaced element` but you still can make a custom dropdown with `HTML`, `CSS` and  `JavaScript`. Mainly that dropdown is a container `div` with some other `div`s inside it that act as the options and now you can style the custom one and hide the real `select` element.

Comment: @Arthemoon a popular javascript plugin for this is [select2](https://select2.org/). `select` elements are notorious for not being able to be styled fully.